# Estimating Feynman diagrams for $B_s \rightarrow \mu \mu$ decays

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, electroweak

Is there a straightforward way to infer the relative contributions of each diagram depicted ([from this blog](http://resonaances.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/another-intriguing-result-about-b.html)) to the $B^0_S \rightarrow \mu^+ \mu^- $ branching fraction?

[image: $B_s \rightarrow \mu \mu decays]

Naively, as they each have 4 vertices so I would expect each to contribute roughly the same order of magnitude based on that alone, but I'm unsure how to easily estimate the loop integral contribution to each diagram. Short of evaluating each diagram and performing the loop integral explicitly, is there a way to estimate the relative contributions of each diagram?

Edit: And if we consider the diagrams obtained from replacing the $Z^0$ with $\gamma$, I suppose that the relative contributions would change depending on energy scale due to the respective running couplings of $\alpha_{EM}$ and $\alpha_s$, adding another layer of complication...